# question about managing values with multiple subvalues in python 3k

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question reguarding how I would perform the following task in python.
(I use python 3k)

what I have are several variables which can yield further variables on top of those
and each of those have even more variables
for example:

a generic name would be

```
item_version_type =
```

where each part (item, version, and type) refer to different variables(here there are 3 for each)

```
item = item_a, item_b, item_c
version = range(1,3)
itemtype = itemtype_a, itemtype_b, itemtype_c
```

simply listing each name and defining it is annoying:

```
itema_ver1_typea = 
itemb_ver1_typea = 
itemc_ver1_typea =
itema_ver2_typea = 
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

especially when I have something where one variable is dependent on something else
for example:

```
if value == True:
    version = ver + 1
```

and to top it off this whole example is rather simply compared to what I'm actually
working with.

one thing I am curious about is using multiple "." type of classes such as:

```
item.version.type
```

I know that this can be done
I just can't figure out how to get a class with more than one dot

either that or if anyone can point me to a better method

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you need to update these values or are they stable after they are created?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do. item.version.type implies that a version has a type. But the type belongs to the item as well as the version if I am not mistaken. Could you clarify this? :)

Comment: What part of Object Oriented design confuses you?  What tutorials are you using to learn Python?  This is an odd question, since it should be covered in every Python tutorial.  Please list the tutorials you're using to learn Python.  It appears that they're not covering any of Python's Object-Oriented programming features.

Answer (score 3):

Grouping of data like this can be done in three ways in Python.

First way is tuples:

```
myvariable = ('Sammalamma', 1, 'Text')
```

The second way is a dictionary:

```
myvariable = {'value': 'Sammalamma', 'version': 1, 'type': 'Text'}
```

And the third way is a class:

```
 class MyClass(object):
     def __init__(self, value, version, type):
          self.value = value
          self.version = version
          self.type = type

 >>> myvariable = MyClass('Sammalamma', 1, 'Text')
 >>> myvariable.value
 'Sammalamma'
 >>> myvariable.version
 1
 >>> myvariable.type
 'Text'
```

Which one to use in each case is up to you, although in this case I would claim that the tuple doesn't seem to be the best choice, I would go for a dictionary or a class.

None of this is unique to Python 3, it works in any version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Lennart Regebro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591157/question-about-managing-values-with-multiple-subvalues-in-python-3k/4591441#4591441) if items are immutable:

```
import collections

Item = collections.namedtuple('Item', 'value version type')

items = [Item(val, 'ver'+ver, t)
         for val in 'abc' for ver in '12' for t in ['typea']]      
print(items[0])
# -> Item(value='a', version='ver1', type='typea')
item = items[1]
print(item.value, item.type)
# -> b typea
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for posting this here instead of the comments but I have no clue how to work the site here.

for clarification

what I need is basically to have be able to get an output of said such as where
I could take a broad area (item) narrow it further (version) and even further (type as in type of item like lets say types are spoon, knife, fork)

or a better description is like arm.left.lower = lower left arm
where I could also have like leg.left.lower

so I could have arm.both.upper to get both left and right upper arms
where a value would be assigned to both.

what I need is to be able to do truth tests etc. and have it return the allowable values
such as

if leg == True

output is --> leg.both.lower, leg.both.upper, leg.left.upper leg.right.upper, etc., etc., etc.

if upper == True

output is --> leg.both.upper, leg.left.upper, etc., etc., etc.

hopefully that helps

Basically I get how to get something like `item.version` but how do I get something
like `item.version.type`

I need to have it to be more specific than just item.version
I need to be able to tell if item is this and version is that then type will be x

like
item.version.type

```
if version == 3:
    item.version = spoon.3.bent
#which is different from
if version == 2:
    item.version.type = spoon.2.bent
```